# Not able to setup actions-on-google sample using ActionsSDK

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to setup an assistant app with the following example https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-say-number-nodejs . I can see that the assistant app endpoint is working fine, because I get back the response I configured to it in my code. **But the conversation is not reaching my API**, when I reply back to the MAIN intent's question.

Here is the example, whats it is showing 
[image]

`I found few places within 7.8 miles` is not sent from my API. Am I missing something? I modified the code to make it work as nodejs app using express.js.

Here are the codes

```
# index.js
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const ActionsSdkApp = require('actions-on-google').ActionsSdkApp;
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Constants

// App
const expressApp = express();

expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;        // set our port
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

var router = express.Router();

const NO_INPUTS = [
  'I didn\'t hear that.',
  'If you\'re still there, say that again.',
  'We can stop here. See you soon.'
];

function process_request(request, response) {
//exports.sayNumber = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new ActionsSdkApp({request, response});

  function mainIntent (app) {
    console.log('mainIntent');
    let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
      'I can read out an ordinal like ' +
      '<say-as interpret-as="ordinal">123</say-as>. Say a number.</speak>', NO_INPUTS);
    app.ask(inputPrompt);
  }

  function rawInput (app) {
    console.log('rawInput');
    if (app.getRawInput() === 'bye') {
      app.tell('Goodbye!');
    } else {
      let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>You said, <say-as interpret-as="ordinal">' +
        app.getRawInput() + '</say-as></speak>', NO_INPUTS);
      app.ask(inputPrompt);
    }
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, mainIntent);
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.TEXT, rawInput);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
};

router.get('/googleBot', function(req, res) {
    console.log("received a get request");
    process_request(req, res)
});
router.post('/googleBot', function(req, res) {
    console.log("received a post request");
    process_request(req, res)
});


expressApp.use('/', router);

expressApp.listen(port, HOST);
//console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

Here is the action.json

```
# action.json
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "conversation_1"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "conversation_1": {
      "name": "conversation_1",
      "url": "https://<myownsite>.xyz/googleBot",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running the node.js with `node index.js` and I have it reverse proxied to `https://<myownsite>.xyz/googleBot` it works great when I made Curl request.

**Request**

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Google-Actions-API-Version: 2" https://mysitexxx.com/googleBot -d '{"user":{"userId":"<hidden for obvious reasons>","locale":"en-US","lastSeen":"2017-12-11T09:22:58Z"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1512984211990","type":"NEW"},"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"KEYBOARD","query":"12"}]}],"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]}]}'
```

and I get back response saying " You said 12" when I use Curl.

**Response**

```
{"conversationToken":"{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}","expectUserResponse":true,"expectedInputs":[{"inputPrompt":{"initialPrompts":[{"ssml":"<speak>You said, <say-as interpret-as=\"ordinal\">12</say-as></speak>"}],"noInputPrompts":[{"ssml":"I didn't hear that."},{"ssml":"If you're still there, say that again."},{"ssml":"We can stop here. See you soon."}]},"possibleIntents":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT"}]}]}
```

**So, am I Missing something here ?**

**UPDATE**

Here is the information from request and response tabs of simulator(on the right side)

**Request**

```
{
  "request": {
    "conversationToken": "",
    "debugLevel": 1,
    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "mockLocation": {
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 37.421980615353675,
        "longitude": -122.08419799804688
      },
      "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
      "zipCode": "94043"
    },
    "query": "Talk to my test app",
    "surface": "PHONE"
  },
  "response": {},
  "debug": {},
  "errors": []
}
```

**Response**

`this part is null; I don't see anything, but still simulator UI says "Hi! I can read out an ordinal number like 123. Speak or say a number."`

**UPDATE2**

**request** Welcome message posted with `actions.intent.TEXT` as requested in the comments

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Google-Actions-API-Version: 2" https://mysitexyz.com/googleBot -d '{ "conversationToken": "{}", "expectUserResponse": true, "expectedInputs": [ { "inputPrompt": { "initialPrompts": [ { "textToSpeech": "<speak>Welcome</speak>" } ], "noInputPrompts": [] }, "possibleIntents": [ { "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT" } ], "speechBiasingHints": [ ] } ] }'
```

**response**

```
Action Error: no matching intent handler for: null
```

**Request with MAIN intent** .

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Google-Actions-API-Version: 2" https://mysitezyx.com/googleBot -d '{"user":{"userId":"<hidden for obvious reasons>","locale":"en-US","lastSeen":"2017-12-11T09:22:58Z"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1512984211990","type":"NEW"},"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.MAIN","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"KEYBOARD","query":"Welcome"}]}],"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]}]}'
```

**response**

```
{"conversationToken":"{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}","expectUserResponse":true,"expectedInputs":[{"inputPrompt":{"initialPrompts":[{"ssml":"<speak>Hi! <break time=\"1\"/> I can read out an ordinal number like <say-as interpret-as=\"ordinal\">123</say-as>. Speak or say  a number.</speak>"}],"noInputPrompts":[{"ssml":"I didn't hear that."},{"ssml":"If you're still there, say that again."},{"ssml":"We can stop here. See you soon."}]},"possibleIntents":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT"}]}]}
```

Comment: That is, to be honest, very very strange. It looks like you're doing that through the simulator. Can you select the first part of the conversation (the "Talk to..." and the welcome response) and show the Request, Result, and Debug tabs to the right in the simulator as well?

Comment: @Prisoner updated the debug tab information

Comment: In your action json you replaced https://<myownsite>.xyz/googleBot by your side with the corretc port 5000? As inside the express initializing? And In simulator you used the Change Version link? After you updated your action.json with the running gactions.exe (or gactions.bat)

Comment: There should be one more tab to the right of the Response tab. What is it labeled and what are its contents?

Comment: @Prisoner at Action on Google and Action SDK without Dialogflow. I think there the Simulator Debug tabs are not working correctly I have the same problem.  Just the message window is correct for me but not for rrmerugu . Maybe this Simulator Debug Window problem depends on the Responses or on the Action.JSON ?

Comment: Yeah. The api is pointed to the right url in action.json and the port 5000 to the nginx correctly and I'm able to make a call to api and get the expected response as show the updated description

Comment: ok try maybe to respond with {
    "conversationToken": "{}",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [
        {
            "inputPrompt": {
                "initialPrompts": [
                    {
                        "textToSpeech": "<speak>Welcome</speak>"
                    }
                ],
                "noInputPrompts": []
            },
            "possibleIntents": [
                {
                    "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
                }
            ],
            "speechBiasingHints": [ ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: by hand instead of the nodejs google action sdk answer. but Actually it is guessing into the blue. I have no idea whats the reason. The response above is working for me so i thaught you can try it maybe. The difference is the texttoSpeech parameter instead of the ssml parameter inside

Comment: I would also try a `curl` command that hits the MAIN intent and post what its response is if you go directly. I don't think the problem is with the TEXT intent - it sounds more like the microphone is being closed after the welcome - although the code suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Prisoner as you can see in the image I attached, conversation is closed after the it have some response(is this what you mean microphone closed ?).  ok I will post request and response of "Talk to my test app" message(MAIN intent)

Comment: Yup, I see. But the response to your "28" message also suggests that it actually closed it, or somehow triggered not listening, before then. I want to see how it is responding to the initial message because that might be what is causing the problem, rather than a problem with the second message.

Comment: @shortQuestion I tried the one you suggested, And I updated the response in the description

Comment: @Prisoner I updated the MAIN intent response in the description.

Comment: @rrmerugu you did my one as request I mean that message as response to the request from your server to the google action server. (or as response to your curl request). Instead of the autogenerated one from the google action sdk.

Comment: in your code like that: but double check for syntax errors :                                                                       function mainIntent (app) {
    console.log('mainIntent');
   response.send("!!!!!!!!!!!!place the JSON_ here!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  }

Comment: Instead of app.ask()/app.tell() you want me to use response.send() ?

Comment: jep like that here in pastebin: pastebin.com/jPMXi5Qs This respond without the google app sdk.  I hope that it work anyway if the rest is handled by the sdk try with curl first if it works correctly (syntax errors etc.) and than try the google simulator if at least the first question after the welcome answer works

Comment: @shortQuestion I changed the welcome intent in the code as you suggested and it returns "Welcome" which is good. but then I typed 12 and it says "What do you mean?"(my test app left the conversation) .

Comment: seems as it cant find or send the free text intent... strange. i will try to rebuild the problem later and check in company if i can find out what happen.

Comment: did your server recived something shortly before it says what do you mean? Hmm probably not i guess cause there is no unhandled intent in the action.json

Comment: @shortQuestion it didn't receive any logs regarding the message I typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of struggle and help form @shortQuestion, we have finally come to a conclusion that this issue is because of some permission issue. And turns out I use google business email and our admin didn't enable few `Activity Controls` especially `Web & App Activity`. Just turn on `Web & App Activity` in https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols and ask your admin to enable the Web & App activity for you/all the people who need access to assistant test.

Too bad that Google didn't throw this error at any point of time.

Answer (score 1):

So I rebuild your case I just use the nodejs express boilerplate from webstorm instead of exact your code.

I fixed some problems inside so this github is working: [voice google home action boilerplate](https://github.com/haukedau/googleActionsInit)

If you have questions just ask.

The only point where i had only the welcome intent but not the other intents working was when i created everything b ut forgot to click on change version in google action console after i updated the action.json and run gaction.exe:

[image: update action json version]

After I fixed that i got a lot of error 500 from my server until i changed the line

```
 app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
      'I can read out an ordinal like ' +
      '<say-as interpret-as="ordinal">123</say-as>. Say a number.</speak>', NO_INPUTS);
```

to

```
 app.buildInputPrompt(false, '<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
      'I can read out an ordinal like ' +
      '<say-as interpret-as="ordinal">123</say-as>. Say a number.</speak>');
```

After this i had to fix some bugs caused by myself and now is all working.

**Update:**
So the problem in the end was solved by using another google account. Probably cause of some google cloud permission settings. Not fully sure with it. But if some have same problems, checkout your permissions and accout rules.

Comment: yep hoply it works for you soon, the gaction.exe need to be added to my repo i forgot that the standard github/webstorm settings dont upload it. If you find some trouble just ask.

Comment: hey, got some weird, reasons, its now working me, I did everything mentioned in your README, 1. I started the `node start`, 2. ngroked port 5000 and got this https://66fb5657.ngrok.io(I will keep this for a while for you to try incase needed ) 3. updated  url in action.json and the gactions with command, 4. clicked the change version >. Actions on Google-Draft Version selected > DONE button. 6. tested it still fails :(

Comment: now the second message actually says "What do you mean?"

Comment: between, where can I check the what fulfilment url the project is using  in the dashboard. any idea on that?

Comment: No i think the dashboard there is not helpful. Did you recieved any request  message in your ngrok panel? From google and is ngrok running on correct port. After change version did you clicked on update draft as well?

Comment: My question is did the server print anything as console.log or did ngrok recived any ingoing calls from google actions? If Error 500 it pretend as well that nothing is there. If what do you mean in second message shows up this actually means that it dont use the correct action.json

Comment: yes server is printing         console.log('mainIntent') for the "talk to my test app"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161217/discussion-between-rrmerugu-and-shortquestion).

Comment: after our chat and screen share i have to say its really strange... the following points i would check: gactions action.json upload on other operating system (maybe mac version has problems?), google cloud permission settings are the permissions to change and update the project, correct setted to you? Some other connection related things. but actually when i uploaded the action json on my for my google simulator account on your ngrok address it works

Comment: Yeah.   It's totally wierd that it was working a week ago for me and now it's not

Comment: ok. I finally tried with another account, the same code, ngrok Api worked on it

Comment: must be something to do with the org level permissions on my account. my peronal account doesn't have anything and it worked. But I wish google has better way of throwing errors than this.

Comment: oh yes, the errors are saying really to less. actually the gaction said all ok even

Comment: yes everything works with ngrok, when I created a project with my personal account and configured it .

Comment: perfect so all done now thanks for the upvote :-) and have a good day